# Using python requests login github

Tags: python, networking, python-requests

I'm trying to login github using python requests. In the login page, I find I need the following data to post to server.

```
       commit: Sign in
       authenticity_token:    3YV9FG87QiYCga1Ue3IGMRSh88uDWBBhVW2Plwd22uDe+CBPbK/n+I+TC0ozTBsvk7QEPjNdFLvCil/9mdMr5A==    ga_id: 642223273.1583769258
       login: XXX
       password: XXX
       webauthn-support: supported
       webauthn-iuvpaa-support: unsupported
       return_to: 
       required_field_57c4: 
       timestamp: 1583770320678
       timestamp_secret:    fdc0b523bcd384d633c714f78fc8fd5d909dde3a05c0501345f358af2890fdec
```

I can get 'ga_id' from login page using chrome, but when I use python request to get login page.html, I found it's content is blank.

The following data was getting by chrome:

meta name="octolytics-dimension-ga_id" content="**740927323.1583770634**" class="js-octo-ga-id"

while when I use python requests, I got data like this, but the content is blank.

meta name="octolytics-dimension-ga_id" content="" class="js-octo-ga-id"

```
import requests
import re

def login():

    headers = {
            'Referer': 'https://github.com/',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36',
            'Host': 'github.com',
    }

    url1 = "https://github.com/login"
    response = session.get(url1, headers=headers).content
    print(response)
```

When I print response, I found the "octolytics-dimension-ga_id" content is blank. Why?

Comment: Instead of logging in from the web page, did you check Github REST API? https://developer.github.com/v3/

Comment: You really should use the API as suggested by ionpoint.

Comment: Thanks very much, I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case if you would like to know how to login using your code, so here is the correct way. But be informed that `GitHub` is already offering [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication) which you can use for the login.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re


def Main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        r = req.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
        token = soup.find("input", {'data-csrf': 'true'}).get("value")
        timest = soup.find("input", {'name': 'timestamp'}).get("value")
        timestsc = soup.find(
            "input", {'name': 'timestamp_secret'}).get("value")
        rq = soup.find(
            "input", {'type': 'text', 'name': re.compile("^required_field")}).get("name")
        data = {
            'commit': 'Sign+in',
            'authenticity_token': token,
            'login': 'test@test.com',
            'password': 'lalala',
            'webauthn-support': 'supported',
            'webauthn-iuvpaa-support': 'unsupported',
            'return_to': '',
            rq: '',
            'timestamp': timest,
            'timestamp_secret': timestsc
        }
        r = req.post(url, data=data)
        print(r.text)


Main("https://github.com/session")
```

> Since we haven't included valid `user/pass` so if you checked the output. you will find the following which confirm we are on the correct way.

Output:

```html
Incorrect username or password.
```